# 404 Page Not Found When Viewing Images Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have an image stored in the database as *conventions/convention_title.jpg*

The file is located in **"storage/app/conventions/convention_title.jpg"**

When i do something like this flyer }}">, it doesn't display...

**OR**

**flyer }}">** the image still wont display...

And even worse still, if i try to access the image directly via link like this...

*http://localhost:8000/storage/app/convention/convention_title.jpg* i get a view not found error -> 404 page not found..

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new disk in the **config/filesystems.php**

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path(),
    ],
    'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
    ],
]
```

Then use it :

```
Storage::disk('uploads')->put('filename', $file_content);
```

Or you can do this simple method

```
$request->file('photo')->move(public_path("/uploads"), $newfilename);
```

Then, using any of the above methods, you can still access your images using the asset() helper function...

Answer (score 6):

1. `php artisan storage:link`
2. problem solved while writing

```
src=" {{ asset('/storage/'.$post->image) }}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Web content must be stored on the laravel root  `/public` folder and you can easily access to it via [asset helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset).

For example:

`/public/img/conventions/convention_title.jpg`

Then you can access on the views to it like:

`{{ asset("/img/conventions/convention_title.jpg")}}`

In case you want to test if you can access to the image you can try:

```
http://localhost:8000/convention/convention_title.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks buddy... How do I upload images into the public folder?

Comment: You can have a look @InspiredPrynceKaka https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/image-upload-using-storage-function-to-public-folder?page=1

Comment: I did not realize you didn't need the public path for the asset() function. Thank you so much!